# mXparser Agument decimal value exception

Tags: c#

So I have a problem trying to set mXparser Argument with a decimal value.

```
        public void SetArguments(List<decimal> argumentsValues)
    {
        _x = new List<Argument>();
        var argsNumber = argumentsValues.Count;
        for (int i = 1; i < argsNumber + 1; i++)
            _x.Add(new Argument("x" + i + "=" + argumentsValues[i-1]));

        if (argsNumber == 1)
        {
            _expression = new Expression(_base, f, _x[0]);
        }
        if(argsNumber==2)
        {
            _expression = new Expression(_base, f, _x[0], _x[1]);
```

Here is sample of my function. _x[0] appears as 0 another thing is that when I calculate expression and trying to conver the result to decimal I am getting OverflowException (because I am trying to convert NaN to decimal). I really need to pass float values to the function arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. It was enaugh to change

```
_x.Add(new Argument("x" + i + "=" + argumentsValues[i-1]));
```

To

```
_x.Add(new Argument("x" + i, argumentsValues[i-1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your were trying to use "natural language" constructor i.e.

```
Argument x = new Argument("x = 5");
Argument x = new Argument("x = 2*2 + sin(pi/2)");
```

which is very handy, but requires additional parsing and is not optimal in case you have argument name and argument value. More optimal (performance and some special cases) is

```
Argument x = new Argument("x", 5);
```

Please refer to the list of Argument constructors given in the API specification
http://mathparser.org/api/org/mariuszgromada/math/mxparser/Argument.html

and take look on the tutorial section related to user defined arguments
http://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/user-defined-arguments/

You will see there different argument types (including dependent arguments) + usage of different constructors.

Best regards